# Cannot download file Symfony 3.4 and VueJS

Tags: php, symfony, vue.js

I spent time before asking this question

I want to download file from local directory `/Users/Desktop/symfony/project_dem/app/Resources/file.webm,` but i always get something wrong.

So my controller

```
public function getUrl(Request $request) 
{   
    $response = new BinaryFileResponse($file);
    $response->setAutoEtag(true);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'video/webm');
    return $response;
}
```

in VueJS

```
axios.post('/api', {
    url: this.url,
    responseType: 'blob',
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);

    let blob = new Blob([response.data], {
            type: 'video/webm'
        }),
        url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    window.open(url);

}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

I get in console log for `response.data` like this

[image]

**

### What I found wrong is why the size of the file in server 6.2 MB and after a download is 11.2 maybe this is error BinaryFileResponse ?

**

Anyone can tell me what I did wrong  ? and thanks.

Comment: Does the screenshot represent the output of ` console.log(response.data);` or `console.log(error);`?

Comment: Hi @Jovan Perovic, it represent the output of console.log(response.data);

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that the output of **console.log(response.data)** is showing a binary file. I mean the file is there. You are not clear when you say

> but I always get something wrong

Try this

```
axios.post('/api', {
    url: this.url,
    responseType: 'blob',
}).then((response) => { 
    let blob = new Blob([response.data], {
        type: 'video/webm'
    });
    url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    window.open(url);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

In my opinion, the issue here is that you did not put a semi colon at the end of the line where you created the blob.

Comment: i test it but not work, why i see wrong because i get file with different size in server 6.3 MB and when i download i get 11.2 MB

Comment: Are you using nginx or apache? Maybe some kind of file compression

Comment: I use ./bin/console server:run